# Is it possible to call payable functions of smart contract using web3j’s smart contract wrappers?

Tags: web3j, java, payable

How do we call payable functions of smart contract using web3j?

UPDATE:

I'm going to change generated smart contract wrapper class manually. Now I have:

```
    public Future<TransactionReceipt> uploadSignedString(Uint256 verificationId,
                                                     Utf8String signedString) {
    Function function = new Function("uploadSignedString",
            Arrays.<Type>asList(
                    verificationId,
                    signedString
            ),
            Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());

    return executeTransactionAsync(function);
}
```

and I'm going to add manually:

```
public TransactionReceipt uploadSignedStringPayable(Uint256 verificationId,
                                                    Utf8String signedString,
                                                    BigInteger weiValue)
        throws InterruptedException, TransactionTimeoutException, IOException {
    Function function = new Function(
            "uploadSignedString",
            Arrays.<Type>asList(
                    verificationId,
                    signedString
            ),
            Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());

    return executeTransaction(FunctionEncoder.encode(function), weiValue);
}
```

and as I see it can be done only as a sync call.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Did you try calling a payable function and send required ethers/weis in value?

Comment: It seems to be here with version 2.3.0 of web3j. This included also async Transactions with a weiValue.

Comment: https://github.com/web3j/web3j/pull/138 by max taldykin was included in ver. 2.3.0 
Thanks, Max!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Since version 2.3.0 web3j generates wrappers with additional argument `weiValue` for payable functions.

E.g. such code is generated

```
public Future<TransactionReceipt> pay(Utf8String name, BigInteger weiValue) {
    Function function = new Function("pay", Arrays.<Type>asList(name), Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
    return executeTransactionAsync(function, weiValue);
}
```

for this Solidiy code:

```
function pay(string name) payable public {}
```

---

**Old answer**

Seems that it is not possible in current version of web3j.

Here is the wrapper code it generates for a payable function without arguments:

```
public Future<TransactionReceipt> foo() {
    Function function = new Function("foo", Arrays.<Type>asList(), Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
    return executeTransactionAsync(function);
}
```

`executeTransactionAsync` does not accept ether, but there is synchronous [`executeTransaction(String data, BigInteger weiValue)`](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/3050d7f23e235702bf658ca5565517be1415a9d2/src/main/java/org/web3j/tx/Contract.java#L192) which does.

It is possible to call `foo` along with ether manually:

```
Function function = new Function("foo", Arrays.<Type>asList(), Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
String encodedFunction = FunctionEncoder.encode(function);
Transaction transaction = Transaction.createFunctionCallTransaction(
         from, gasPrice, gasLimit, contractAddress, BigInteger.ONE, encodedFunction);

EthSendTransaction transactionResponse = web3j.ethSendTransaction(transaction).sendAsync().get();
```

Pull request posted: https://github.com/web3j/web3j/pull/138

Comment: I tried applying a function with payable and adding a value in wei but it fails and shows value with transaction on etherscan as 0. Do you have any idea why? @max taldykin